# ImageView ignoring visibility change

Tags: android, android-studio

**I have ImageView:**

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSend"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:onClick="send"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/odeslat"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
```

For some reason `img.setVisibility(View.GONE)` is not working when I use instant run.

How can I get it to work again?

The ID is still the same (before and after the instant run). I also checked all ifs and flags. Code runs normally, it just ignores visibility change.

**EDIT:**
Nothing works on it. (Drawable change, resize...)

**Listener:**

```
final ImageView send = findViewById(R.id.imgSend);

                    if (toSend()) {
                        send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        send.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I've already solved the problem. For some reason the view requires to be re-initialized. ID is still the same, it just does't work. But thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: nice :) happy coding :)

Comment: @GDator ok... It still doesn't work when I rotate the device :(. I don't get it. It's just normal imageview.

Comment: When rotating the device the activity will destroy. So you need to re-instantiate your components. Try to use `onPause` and `onResume`. Try to put all the instantiation of your components to `onResume`.

Comment: @GDator I have everything inside my OnClickListener. It goes through the listener without any warnings or errors. I added my listener into the question.

Comment: what is the `toSend()` function? I think its always true. That's why your condition is not going to else.

Comment: It's not. I've checked it. It returns true when there are messages waiting to be sent.

Comment: Please enlighten me. What do you want to achieve? If you clicked the button and it has messages waiting to be sent? you need to `GONE` the imageview?

Comment: Sorry I said it wrong. The listener listen to object which stores the messages. When I add new message the object triggers the listener. The toSend() returns true when there is new original message.

Comment: So when do you need the `send.setVisibility(View.GONE)` statement? When there is no new message? This code will not go to else. Because when you add new message the `toSend()` function will always be true. Can't see your point here.